# Append multiple lists with another set of lists python and format to insert into datatable

Tags: python, list, append

I have items collected from variable number of 'paired' entry widgets and other predefined data. the 'paired' entry widgets are  'quantity' and 'sell price'.

So far, I can create 2 seperate 'sets of lists' (not formatted how i think they should be).

```
1
2
3
4

('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', ('M',), '10')
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', ('L',), '20')
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', ('XL',), '30')
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', ('XXL',), '40')
```

In the example the 1 2 3 4 is the Quantity and the 10 20 30 40 is the sell price.
I need to format the lists correctly for inserting into a datatable and appended the 2 sets of lists.

```
def addtoorder():
global all_entries , quantity, e, orderref, SO, c, d, sellprice, size, all_prices
orderref = SO.get()

for size, quantity in all_entries[e.get()].items():
    x = quantity.get()  
    print(x)

for size, sellprice in all_prices[e.get()].items():
    y = sellprice.get()
    sell=orderref, c.get(), d.get(), size , y
    print(sell)
```

I believe the required format for inserting into datatable would be

```
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', 'M', '10', '1')
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', 'L', '20', '2')
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', 'XL', '30', '3')
('SO6666', 'PW071', 'Orange', 'XXL', '40', '4')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read up on `zip`.

Comment: thanks. Had played around with zip but couldn't piece it together right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def addtoorder():
    global all_entries , quantity, e, orderref, SO, c, d, sellprice, size, all_prices
    orderref = SO.get() 

all_prices=all_prices[e.get()].items()
all_entries= all_entries[e.get()].items()

for prices,entries in zip(all_prices,all_entries):
    y = prices[1].get()        
    x = entries[1].get()  
    sell=orderref, c.get(), d.get(), prices[0] , y, x
    print(sell)
```

Comment: Thanks @pickplatespiral, I had played around with zip but didn't get it right.
Any idea why/how to get rid of the extra () and , on the size items.

Comment: i inserted this in the code where i original pull all_sizes 

all_sizes = [i[0] for i in all_sizes]

Works perfectly now. 

Thanks